# Traversing a sorted array efficiently in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

We have a sorted array. We can move between 2 consecutive elements if the difference is <= some int k. How can we determine efficiently in C if it is possible to move from a given index to the other?
For example, our sorted array is A[5]={1,3,5,8,20}. and K is given as 2. i.e. we can move between consecutive elements if and only if difference is < or = to K i.e. 2 in this case.
2 indices are given lets take index 0 and 3,i.e. A[0]=1 and A[3]=8. Now we can move from A[0] to A[1] iff A[1]-A[0] <=K, and so on upto A[3]. I have to do this process for multiple values of the indices, so I can be more efficient by storing the past results or something? If yes then how? Thank you.

Comment: some example? and code?

Comment: I have edited the problem with an example

Comment: Well, the obvious thing would just be to go element by element and check.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any better and more efficient method than that :)

Comment: What exactly are you looking for here? Do you have some specific reason to expect that you can do better than the obvious solution? (You can't, by the way.) Or are you just beginning to learn, so the obvious solution isn't yet obvious? Is there any other information you can provide that would be useful to answer the question?

Comment: You can tell that it's definitely not possible if A[3] - A[0] > 3*K.  But A[3] - A[0] <= 3*K doesn't tell you that it *is* possible.

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth Yes we can determine if it's not possible but that doesn't tell about if its possible or not :(

Comment: @user3807678 Exactly. But it keeps you from iterating through all elements in a "clearly lost case".

Answer (score 1):

In the end you'll have to iterate through all elements between index `i` and `j` to verify the distances.

But you could estimate the average distance between the entries to guess whether it's realistic:

- Let's assume you've got indices `i` and `j`. There are `n` elements between them and the maximum allowed distance is `k`.
- Determine the distance `d` between element `i` and element `j`: `d = abs(array[i] - array[j])`.
- Calculate the average distance `a` between those points: `a = d / n`.
- If `a` is bigger than your limit `k`, you know that this won't be a valid range.
- If `a` is indeed smaller or equal to your limit `k`, you'll have to iterate through your elements and verify them.
- Since this iteration works as standalone for all elements between, you're able to multithread the checks if you want to (and it's a reasonable speed gain vs. overhead).

Answer (score 1):

Worst case, you can't do any better than the obvious solution (go element by element and check). Here's an example that demonstrates it:

```
int k = 2;
int a[] = {0, 2, 4, 6, ...};
```

Any element of `a` is reachable from any other. Changing any element of `a` breaks the connection between elements on opposite sides of the changed element, and the only way to detect the disconnection is to examine the specific changed element. That means to determine whether two elements of `a` are connected, you have to examine every element between them, or the one you didn't look at could be the one that breaks the chain.